# Are there proper statistics for browser user shares?

Tags: browser

Like all web companies, Internet Explorer 6 gives us a hard time.

Although Google Analytics statistics from our own websites give a good impression of local browser shares and the way they are developing, I am looking for something on a more global scale.

I have found a "[User share of web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers)" article on Wikipedia, but this article does not go into detail about the specific versions.

**Is there a more detailed, objective view of browser shares, including version numbers?**

Comment: About the ie6 concern, by the way : http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=742029

Comment: Not really an internet explorer specific question, took away the tags.

Comment: Global statistics aren't worth the paper they don't get printed on. The crucial question is: what are **your** customers using?

Comment: We have good insights in what our customers use; some customers, however, are using global statistics as a (wrongful) argument which is why we need these statistics.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Net Applications seems to be a common referent for this: http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2

[image: ALT TAG HERE W00T!!!11111]

They update monthly I think.  Plus you can drill down on a lot of details.

Comment: The long time taken by the image to load gave me a great occasion to admire the beauty of the alt text :]

Comment: An appropriate substitute in lieu of image, I believe.

Comment: Aw man, I just saw that Net Apps was also listed on that Wikipedia article.  Sorry, guess i have nothing to add.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually the ones from W3C : http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Edit : Though they are already mentionned on the wikipedia article you gave.

Comment: I don't know. My guess is that these data are heavily biased. Imagine all those "best viewed in internet explorer 6" sites. Will they include a w3c counter on their pages?

Comment: Problem is that I don't think there is really a way to know, these datas have to be explicitly saved by some counter, hard to know, then, for every website.